# GROUP BY is acting strange returning duplicates as soon as there is more then one document in filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Can anyone guide me why GROUP BY which I'm trying to use to get only one row of data per combination of document number and line item, is returning single line as expected when I filter single document number, but is returning two lines for the same ID as soon as I will remove the filter or add at least one more document number to the filter?

Single document filter:

```sql
SELECT   
    lp.[VBELN]
   ,lp.[POSNR]
FROM SAPECC.LIPS lp
WHERE lp.[VBELN] IN ('2122898111') --, '2122731545')
GROUP BY lp.[VBELN], lp.[POSNR]
ORDER BY lp.[VBELN] DESC, lp.[POSNR]
```

result as expected - 3 out of 4 lines existing for this document in the DB:

| VBELN | POSNR |
| --- | --- |
| 2122898111 | 000010 |
| 2122898111 | 900001 |
| 2122898111 | 900002 |

Uncommented second document number in the filter:

```sql
SELECT   
    lp.[VBELN]
   ,lp.[POSNR]
FROM SAPECC.LIPS lp
WHERE lp.[VBELN] IN ('2122898111', '2122731545')
GROUP BY lp.[VBELN], lp.[POSNR]
ORDER BY lp.[VBELN] DESC, lp.[POSNR]
```

Duplicated row for 2122898111 and 000010:

| VBELN | POSNR |
| --- | --- |
| 2122898111 | 000010 |
| 2122898111 | 000010 |
| 2122898111 | 900001 |
| 2122898111 | 900002 |
| 2122731545 | 000010 |
| 2122731545 | 000020 |

I've tried also approach `WITH cte AS` using `ROW_NUMBER()` and `PARTITION BY` and then filter only when `row = 1` but it produces the same result: row numbers are correct when there is single document number added in `WHERE` and whenever I will remove this filter, all the rows have row = 1 o_O

I've tried also casting **POSNR** to **INT** before `GROUP BY` but it produces the same result.

I'm not an expert in SQL, but I'm very confused by this behavior.

DB is on Azure SQL Server.

Comment: Please don't use images, use tabular text data

Comment: I wanted to show what I actually see as a result so you could compare those queries to avoid comments, that for sure there is something more and I haven't written it.

Comment: We can see what you actually get if you format the results as text. But I can't see your image on my phone. Also you should be providing a [mre] not your complete dataset.

Comment: Hhmm, is there some corruption in your db, because this isn't supposed to happen. Does it help if you do: `FROM SAPECC.LIPS lp (READCOMMITTED)`

Comment: READ COMMITTED doesn't change anything. those are not the latest records in the DB and it is not the transactional one, but daily refreshed snapshot for reporting purposes mainly.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/AKtWRROh . The query behaves as expected.

Comment: did you try to run dbcc checkdb?

Comment: what happens if you wrap your query into another query which does exactly same group by thing? something like: `select a, b, min(c),min(d) from (select a, b, min(c), min(d) from yourtable group by a, b) x group by a, b`

Comment: is the table a "normal" one, or some of those Cosmodb or other external tables?

Comment: Have you tried to compare the output of `CAST(VBELN AS VARBINARY(MAX))` and `CAST(POSNR AS VARBINARY(MAX))` for the duplicate rows? Often I see people getting tripped up by poorly imported data, e.g.: data values that still have trailing non-printable characters in them such as tabs (0x09), linefeeds (0x0A) or carriage returns (0x0D).

Comment: Just tested this cast to VARBINARY, but the values are the same. If those would be different, `GROUP BY` should not work differently if a single or multiple documents are filtered.

Comment: I suggest you script out the `CREATE TABLE` and 'INSERT` for a small sample of data and, if you can reproduce it with that small sample, post the script here.

Comment: if the only 2 things in use are sql-server and ssms this is not possible given the published query and data. You should add table definition as text.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking and most of comments are saying. It is just a plain table on Azure SQL server. I've tested the query in SSMS and Azure Data Studio, but main usage is in Power BI DataFlow, and it was returning those duplicates, so I needed to check. The thing is that it unfortunately happens, so bug on Azure??

Comment: If you have tested locally and in azure and query behaves as expected then suspect power bi.

Comment: Query is doing this strange things when testing. Power BI is the only place where I can fix it, but I want to have it correct from the beginning not to deduplicate some SQL weirdness in Power Query.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've finally got it working, but I still don't know why I had to do it that way in the first place. I still think there is something messed up on the server, but anyway, here is what I did:

```sql
WITH cte AS ( 
    SELECT   
        CONCAT([VBELN],[POSNR]) AS "ID"
       ,MIN(LFIMG)              AS "LFIMG"
    FROM SAPECC.LIPS
    GROUP BY CONCAT([VBELN],[POSNR])
) 

SELECT 
    LEFT(q.[ID], 10) AS "VBELN"
  ,RIGHT(q.[ID], 6) AS "POSNR"
  ,q.[LFIMG]
INTO #tmp_mid 
FROM cte q 

SELECT 
   t.[VBELN]
  ,t.[POSNR]
  ,t.[LFIMG]
  ,lp.[WERKS]
  ,lp.[LGMNG]
  ,lp.[VRKME]
  ,lp.[UMVKZ]
  ,lp.[UMVKN]
FROM #tmp_mid t
LEFT JOIN SAPECC.LIPS lp ON 
      t.[VBELN] = lp.[VBELN] 
  AND t.[POSNR] = lp.[POSNR]
  AND t.[LFIMG] = lp.[LFIMG]
ORDER BY [VBELN] ASC, [POSNR] ASC

DROP TABLE #tmp_mid
```

this is generating deduplicated set of rows for every document as expected.

If anyone will figure out why normal `GROUP BY` over two fields was not working I'll be more than happy to know that.

Comment: *If anyone will figure out...* -- yeah, but you never provided a reproducible example. Not even the table DDL. Neither did you tell if you tried `dbcc checkdb`, It's extremely unlikely that you hit a SQL Server bug.